# MySQL query for data item table with only key and value based on main data table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables

```
data [table]
- id [primary key]
- context

data_items [table]
- item_id [primary key]
- data_id [foreign key]
- key
- value
```

For 'data' table, it will contain something like

```
id    context
--    -------
 1    car
 2    office
 3    car
 4    food
```

For 'data_items' table, it will contain items from the parent 'data' table like

```
item_id   data_id   key     value
-------   -------   -----   ------------
      1         1   name    Benz
      2         1   model   C-Class 
      3         1   price   1000000

      4         2   city    New York
      5         2   name    Empire State
      6         2   floor   5th
      7         2   room    504

      8         1   name    BMW
      9         1   model   528i Sedan
     10         1   price   80000

     11         3   name    Ford
     12         3   model   Hybrid SE
     13         3   price   30000

     14         3   name    Ford
     15         3   model   528i Sedan
     16         3   price   80000

     17         3   name    BMW
     18         3   model   528i Sedan
     19         3   price   80000

     20         2   city    New York
     21         2   name    Chrystler
     22         2   floor   2nd
     23         2   room    24A

     24         4   type    American
     25         4   name    Hamburger
     26         4   price   $50

     27         4   type    Chinese
     28         4   name    Noodle
     29         4   price   $20

     30         2   city    Los Angeles
     31         2   name    US Bank Tower
     32         2   floor   10th
     33         2   room    105C
```

So if I run SQL query something like

```
SELECT * FROM data_items ........ WHERE data_id = 2;
```

it should give me the following list

```
data_id   city          Name             Floor   room
-------   --------      -------------    -----   ----
      2   New York      Empire State     5th     504
      2   New York      Chrysler         2nd     24A
      2   Los Angeles   US Bank Tower    10th    105C
```

And if I run the follwoing SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM data_items ........ WHERE data_id = 4;
```

it should give me the following list

```
data_id   type          Name             price
-------   --------      -------------    ----
      4   American      Hambergur        $50
      4   Chinese       Noodle           $20
```

So my questions are:

1. Do I need a third table to connect these 2 tables?
2. What's the exact SQL command to get the results as above?

Thank you.

Comment: @Mihai I know there are joins, but I can't get my head around how to get the data_item rows into a single item row result, hence the question. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you normalize your data.  You've got a catch-all table that you're filling with items that don't share common characteristics.  Not only does this making querying the table difficult, it makes supporting it a nightmare.  Instead of each `data_id`, have a table for that type, e.g. `car`, `office` and `food` tables.

Comment: I know the main data_id (a query I will run beforehand), so I guess I don't have to JOIN these 2 tables, because I don't need to display 'context' field from the main table. I just have to make child item rows related to a single data_id into a single row, hope that makes sense.

Comment: something is missing from the data_items table. how do you know that item #2 belongs to items 1,2,3 series and not to 8,9,10 for example? you're missing an entity type.

Comment: @Madbreaks Unfortunate I can't normalize the data, because I am trying to create a single cache table containing these data. I think WordPress uses similar strategy with 'post' and 'post_meta' no? I just need to know how to combine these child item rows into a single row related to a single main data_id.

Comment: @mrras Thanks, hence my question 2. above. Do you mean I need another table that act as entity? If yes, I am still confused how I can get the query results as mentioned in the question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of table is called an [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) (entity-attribute-value model), and even though they give a lot of freedom at the moment of inserting data, that data is considerably harder to query than a normalized model (but there are cases where they are useful). For your particular question, you'll need to know previously what are the value for the `data_id` that you want to query, and use different queries for each `data_id`. For instance, to get the results for `data_id = 2`:

```
SELECT  `data_id`,
        MIN(CASE WHEN `key` = 'city' THEN `value` END) AS `city`,
        MIN(CASE WHEN `key` = 'name' THEN `value` END) AS `name`,
        MIN(CASE WHEN `key` = 'floor' THEN `value` END) AS `floor`,
        MIN(CASE WHEN `key` = 'room' THEN `value` END) AS `room`
FROM data_items
WHERE data_id = 2
GROUP BY `data_id`
```

For `data_id = 4`:

```
SELECT  `data_id`,
        MIN(CASE WHEN `key` = 'type' THEN `value` END) AS `type`,
        MIN(CASE WHEN `key` = 'name' THEN `value` END) AS `name`,
        MIN(CASE WHEN `key` = 'price' THEN `value` END) AS `price`
FROM data_items
WHERE data_id = 4
GROUP BY `data_id`
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed SQL. But this seems to be always returning one row no matter what. Even removing Group By clause. For example data_id = 4 should return 2 rows, one for "American" and another for "Chinese" , but it always return "American".

Comment: @user702300 Just realized that you don't have a way to identify which `type` goes with which `name` and `price`. You should at least have another column that tells you that those values are meant for the same row, right now you just have a correlative id, which is meaningless when trying to identify your resulting rows

Comment: I think we are going somewhere. Let's say I added 'row_id' to 'data_items' table to identify the row, where does this row_id fit into your query example above? Thank you!

Comment: @user702300 If you add that column, then it would replace `data_id` in the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Thank you! That worked! Really appreciate for you patience and dedication :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you name your primary keys the same as the table its in, ending in '_id', it will make querying it easier. Also, the use of not null and unique constraints should be considered. Here is a rough example:

data [table]
- data_id [primary key]
- context  unique not null

data_items [table]
- data_items_id [primary key]
- data_id [foreign key] ((data_id and key together must be unique))
- key
- value

Comment: Adding 'data_items_id' is interesting. But do you have idea for the query to retrieve the rows? Thanks!